# Condicionais baseado em tamanho de tela em Java Android

Tags: java, android

Existe algum método que eu posso trabalhar de acordo com o tamanho da tela do dispositivo?

Exemplo: em um dispositivo de 8 polegadas eu vou trabalhar com o shapeRenderer X e com dispositivos de 10 polegadas eu vou usar shapeRenderer Y.

Algo deste tipo:

```
if (screen size = 1280x920) {
    shapeRenderer.x
} else {
    shapeRenderer.Y
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizar o método `getScreenSize()` disponibilizado pela classe Toolkit

Segue um exemplo:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        System.out.println(screenSize.getWidth());
        System.out.println(screenSize.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Repare que este método retorna um valor `double`.
Baseado nisso você calcular proporções de tela para fazer o que deseja.

Segue o [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize()) desta classe.